# What is the authority of the Air Boss at an airshow?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, airshow

Regular ATC operates under regulations like [FAA Order 7110.65](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/ATC/Index.htm) when they control traffic. At an air show, there is typically an "air boss" that manages aircraft within the air show area.

Is the air boss required to have the same training and certification as a regular controller?

Does the air boss operate under the same regulations as regular controllers?

Does the air boss have the same authority as regular controllers?

Answer (score 3):

Air bosses who orchestrate air shows **do not receive special training or certification** . Infact FAA also lacks the resources to inspect all aircraft that participate in air shows

FAA doesn't have certification standards for air bosses . Waivers for customary flight standards are provided to air shows, which then hire people to direct planes in flight.

There is no training in place right now for an air boss

http://www.rgj.com/story/news/2014/03/23/ntsb-hearing-addresses-distance-between-race-course-and-spectators-other-issues/6587627/

However,  typically former air-traffic controllers with a great deal of aviation experience are hired as Air Bosses at Air Shows .

The air boss implements the standards on the FAA waiver

Firms like ICAS provide Air Boss training